# Crash in Eigen when working with mixed row major/col major sparse matrices

Tags: eigen

I'm getting a crash in Eigen 3.3.5 when trying to do something like the below:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> eigenValues(valueBuffer, 1, 100000);

Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> eigenChannels(channelBuffer, 1, 5000);

Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor> sparseChannels = eigenChannels.sparseView(1.0f, 1.e-4f);

Eigen::Map<const Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>> eigenLargeSparseMatrix(5000, 100000, LargeSparseMatrix.Values.Num(), LargeSparseMatrix.OuterStarts.GetData(), LargeSparseMatrix.InnerIndices.GetData(), LargeSparseMatrix.Values.GetData());

eigenValues += (sparseChannels * eigenLargeSparseMatrix);
```

Specifically, it's crashing in Eigen::internal::sparse_sparse_to_dense_product_impl in the inner loop when trying to grab the index of the lhsIt.

Assume that I've already checked that all the sizes of everything are correct, all my buffers are initialized correctly with real memory, etc. I've been going over every detail of this for a few days trying to find an error in my reasoning or logic.

Basically all I'm trying to do is do:

1xn row vector += (1xm row vector * mxn matrix)

where the left side is dense and both right side vector/matrices are sparse.

What appears to be happening from looking at the templated callstack is the add_assign_op correctly recognizes that the row vector has the RowMajor flag and the matrix is ColMajor, but then the sparse_sparse_to_dense_product_impl has both the lhs and rhs being ColMajor.

From looking at the sparse_sparse_to_dense_product_selector code, this appears to be because Eigen just changes the RowMajor lhs into a ColMajorLhs and calls the product impl. This seems bound to crash- it's a row vector for a reason, I'm not sure why eigen finds the need to transpose it. I'm really unsure how this is mean to work.

My challenge is I need (for memory streaming efficiency), the larger matrix to be organized sequentially in memory such that either a) it's col major, and being pre-multiplied by a row vector, or b) it's row major and being post multiplied by a col vector. Both versions hit this weird transpose code rather than just letting them be different.

Can anyone lend a hand? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

ADDED:
I'm reasonable sure the crash is my own fault at this point after all, but I'd still like to understand why the row vector is being transposed before the multiply, as I would assume this would produce undesirable behavior. Basically at this point, I would just like to understand why the sparse_sparse_to_dense_product_selector transposes row vectors into column vectors before the multiply.

Comment: Did you check the most recent Eigen version or the development branch? Does `eigenValues.transpose() += eigenLargeSparseMatrix.transpose() * sparseChannels.transpose();` work? Can you try providing a [mre] (generate some random data for that)?

Comment: I haven't checked the dev branch, but the most recent version doesn't make any changes to the file in question. I've edited my post above with more info.